# Declarando variable del mismo tipo de la clase que la contiene

Tags: c#, variables, estructuras-de-datos, diseño-de-clases

Saludos he estado estudiando estructuras de datos y me he topado con una sintaxis muy curiosa y he estado tratando de buscar respuestas y no he encontrado.

```
public class CNodo
{

    //Aqui colocamos el dato o datos que guarda el nodo
    private int dato;

    //Esta variable de referencia es usada para apuntar al nodo siguiente
    private CNodo siguiente = null;

    //Propiedades que usaremos
    public int Dato { get => dato; set => dato = value; }
    internal CNodo Siguiente { get => siguiente; set => siguiente =  value; }

    //Para su facil impresion
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("[{0}]", dato);
    }
}
```

He creado una clase llamada `CNodo` y dentro de ella declaré una variable llamada `siguiente` de tipo `CNodo`. El código no tiene ningún error. Pero tengo una confusión. He visto este tipo de variables en varios códigos y aun no entiendo su funcionalidad.

¿Quiero una explicación sobre la utilidad de estas declaraciones de variables?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido, sí, declarar **objetos** del mismo tipo de su clase, es algo totalmente válido, suelen usarse mucho para realizar árboles, te esta generando conflicto el código?, yo editaría la pregunta, porque puede ser cerrada por ser muy amplia, saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Este tipo de construcción la usas para generar listas, en particular listas ligadas. Con esta estructura puedes recorrer la lista apuntando al siguiente elemento de ella en tu campo nombrado como siguiente.

En este caso, es muy útil para manejar pilas, colas, listas y árboles.

Comment: Exacto, una lista ligada es lo que trato de hacer. Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Te daré un ejemplo, si alguna vez viste una tabla en `SQL` que tenga relación a si misma, esto a nivel de `clases` algo muy similar, tomando como ejemplo practico una clase `Persona` e intentaremos poder identificar el parentesco entre sus padres, para lo cual crearíamos una clase con propiedades del mismo tipo de la clase:

```
public class Persona
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Apellido { get; set; }
    public bool Sexo { get; set; }
    public Persona Padre { get; set; }
    public Persona Madre { get; set; }

}
```

Esto tiene varias utilidades como por ejemplo poder definir jerarquías, arboles, pilas, secuencias, etc.
Espero te sirva, saludos

Comment: Saludos! me  haz aclarado mucho la duda con tu ejemplo. No sabia sobre este tipo de relación seguiré investigando partiendo desde aquí. Gracias.